# Ionic Vibration not working in IOS mobile browser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, vibration, ionic-cordova

Hi every one I am working on chat app and it is deploy as **web** and I added vibration on sending any message.

the vibration is working fine on **android chrome mobile browser** but not working on iOS.

`import { Vibration } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/vibration/ngx'; this.vibration.vibrate(1000);`

any advise why is that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Vibration API is not available on safari

https://caniuse.com/vibration